# Entity Framework & udl

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, database-connection

Just recently found the concept of Universal Data Link (.udl) for specifying database connection information.

I have been wondering how to get or edit the connection string for a specific user of the .NET WPF app after the app has been deployed. Some users host the application's database on local computer, some on company's server and some on cloud server.

Since the app has only one and the same installation package for all users, obviously the connection properties cannot be set beforehand straight into the app. I don't also want to go and adjust manually anything in front of the user but rather offer a wizard or simple UI for a user to adjust the connection string.

I'm wondering if .udl file can be used with Entity Framework 4 for that. The backed is PostgreSQL. 
I'm looking for practical implementation/code examples how to achieve this.